# SQL инъекции в телеграмм боте

Tags: python, telegram, sql-injection

Всем привет. Скачал исходник бота-магазина, все настроил и т.п., но слышал про такую штуку как SQL инъекции. Как проверить есть ли она в моем боте? Если есть, то как защититься ?

Сам попробовал методом тыка проверить есть ли она, но ничего дельного не вышло. Прошу помочь, если кто-то может.

Comment: Проверьте исходный код — весь ввод пользователя должен экранироваться

Answer (score 0):

обратите внимание на код. если в нем есть места в которых вы получаете данные от пользователя и сразу же подставляете их в запрос, то это, скорее всего, уязвимость.

Ну вот такой гипотетический пример. Вы пытаетесь авторизовать пользователя по паролю. Пароль в БД.

```
def echo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    if session.execute(f"select * from jeeves_wallet where address='{update.message.text}'").fetchone():
        r = "success"
    else:
        r = "denied"
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=r)
```

Тогда пользователь вместо пароля, может отправить такую штуку `anytext' or true--` и это его авторизует.

Вот такие места, прямого использования пользовательского ввода в коде программы нужно найти и как-то исправить. Этот пример исправляется довольно просто

```
def echo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    if session.execute(f"select * from jeeves_wallet where address='%s'", update.message.text).fetchone():
        r = "success"
    else:
        r = "denied"
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=r)
```

Также поможет и нормальное использование ORM

```
def echo(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    if PasswordsTable.query.filter_by(phrase=update.message.text).first():
        r = "success"
    else:
        r = "denied"
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=r)
```

Просто держите в голове, любой юзер инпут это потенциальная уязвимость.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь уловил.  А как вообще происходит сам процесс ? Как пользователь может ввести свои аргументы в запрос к бд ? Он же по сути выполняет условную команду /start. Дальше уже ему начисляется стандартный баланс, присваивается айди и т.д., но он кроме как командой /start ничего не может сделать.

Comment: ну значит там нет уязвимости)

Comment: А что насчет /start?=и тут sqli инъекция?

Comment: еще раз. "места, прямого использования пользовательского ввода в коде программы нужно найти"